# How to toggle developer mode in Nokia 8110 4G?

Tags: nokia, kaios

There is no menu entry in *Nokia 8110 4G* to switch to developer mode. How can you enable it without hacking firmware?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special key code to toggle developer mode in *Nokia 8110 4G*. Just dial `*#*#33284#*#*` to enable or disable developer mode. The number 33284 can be dialled by typing the [phone word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword) "debug" on your phone.

The code is not saved in the dial history. That means you would need to type it from scratch each time you use it. As a short cut you can store it in the address book. Unfortunately you can not dial it using the address book entry directly. But when you start typing `*#*#` the address book automatically suggests this entry and you do not need to type the rest of it.